# Internet Explorer 8 shows gradient instead of background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a weird error. I'm tiling a semi-transparent 1x1 pixel yellow [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) image in a DIV that overlays some text. With *normal* browsers, everything looks like it should. There's some text and a yellow, semi-transparent overlay above it.

[image: This is how it looks in Chrome]

In Internet Explorer 8 however, instead of tiling the 1x1 PNG image, a gradient (!) is displayed.

[image: This is how it looks in Internet Explorer 8]

The CSS is rather simple:

```
.edit_section_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 150;

  top: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  right: -6px;

  border: 1px solid #afad9d;
  background: url('../../images/content/edit/section/overlay/background-color.png') repeat;

  min-height: 34px;
  cursor: move;
}
```

I've never seen a bug like this before and Google doesn't help me…

Here's a demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), http://jsfiddle.net/jUVfS/

Comment: Can you give us a link to a demo site? And why do you use a semi-transparent background *image* instead of a semi-transparent background *color* in the first place?

Comment: 100% sure you're not using any IE specific css? Very strange effect

Comment: @phihag Here's a demo on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jUVfS/ (I'm using IE8.0.7600.16385)

Comment: @Alex Absolutely no IE-Specific stuff, check out the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jUVfS/

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Your `.png` image needs to have larger dimensions, at *minimum* `1x2` instead of `1x1`.

See: http://nemesisdesign.net/blog/coding/ie8-1x1px-semi-transparent-background-bug/

> Internet Explorer 8 doesn't perform
>   the repeat of a 1x1 pixel
>   semi-transparent background image
>   correctly when any other element on
>   the page is using the "-ms-filter"
>   drective for the alpha transparency.

Comment: I am surprised that more people haven't been here and up voted this issue and answer as it is so common! +1