# Is it possible to use repeating background images in sprites?

Tags: css, css-sprites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Sprites and repeating backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051784/css-sprites-and-repeating-backgrounds)

Are there any tricks that makes it possible to use sprite images as repeatable backgrounds?

Comment: http://www.phpied.com/background-repeat-and-css-sprites/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can but there are some limitations and it depends how the images are repeated. Here is how you would go about this depending on repeat direction:

Repeat: Don't think this is possible.

repeat-X: You would stack these vertically in your sprite sheet. You can only have one image per "row". All images must have the same width.

repeat-y: You would line the iages horizontally and have only one image per "column". All images must have the same height.

You are also limited to having separate sprite sheets for each repeat/no-repeat method.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not really. Not even CSS3 offers an approach to do this properly (there is the proprietary `image-rect` property as shown in the duplicate question but it's not supported by all browsers).

Comment: You can, but there are limitations.